# How to play Video HTML5 from blob file oracle?

Tags: php, html

This is my HTML5 code to play video file from database oracle (Blob file) :

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="getVideo.php" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
```

Video which i upload is mp4, so i take mp4 type in my code.. 
and this is my PHP (getVideo.php) code to get video file from database :

```
<?php
$conn = ocilogon('user', 'pass', '//localhost/XE');

$sql = "SELECT VIDEO FROM TFILE";
$stid = ociparse($conn,$sql);
$rowResult = ocifetch($stid);
settype($arrayResult,"array");
if($rowResult != null){
    echo (OCIResult($stid,'VIDEO')->load());
}
?>
```

but, it's not work, video can't play..
anybody can help me??

thank's before..

Comment: Open getVideo.php in the browser and look if the binary data are really printed. If so, try sending correct MIME type, `header('Content-type: video/mp4')`.

Comment: @duri post as an answer.

Comment: I ask myself, when you deliver a video like this, has it still it's streaming capabilities and can a user jump within the video before the whole file is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Open getVideo.php in the browser and look if the binary data are really printed. If so, try sending correct MIME type: call `header('Content-type: video/mp4')` at the beginning. I'd also call `exit` after `echo`ing the blob to ensure no (whitespace) characters are printed later.

Comment: sory, i forget to add load function on OciResult, i had added that's function above.

Comment: Maybe I would also check whether the video has been loaded correctly and if not return a generated 404-page instead.

Comment: @duri
when i try getVideo.php on my browser the output is binary data. but, when it try to play the video in html5, it's still not work.. :(   the output just show video frame, but i can't play it.

Comment: Which browser are you using for testing? I ask because Firefox can't play MP4, it only plays OGG or WebM.